# No_cursor_blinking doesn't work

Tags: vimrc, cursor

I have read [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor) & I added `se gcr+=a:blinkon0` in my vimrc to stop blinking cursor in my Vim, also I sourced my vimrc again but the matter is it doesn't work & cursor is still blinking in all modes. Please let me know why it doesn't work for me & How can I fix it?

*Edit 1:*

OS: Fedora Linux 27 x86_64 & Vim version: 8.0

*Edit 2:* 
I think I have found a solution for that. Actually Herb Wolfe was right and this option seems not working on Vim (but in gvim it works fine). For stop cursor blinking you can disable cursor blinking in your terminal emulator instead. Also [this wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes) may help.

Comment: Which operating system are you using, and are you using vim or gvim? The article states that the OS has to support it, and that particular option appears to only apply to gvim.

Comment: Question edited. I didn't see that article refer to OS supporting for that feature so this feature can't work on VIm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In gvim you use:

```
set guicursor+=a:blinkon0
```

In vim run in the terminal you would change the terminal setting to disable the blinking.